# How to configure correctly DNS for 2 servers: one for web, another one for mails?

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server

For email server I use `iredmail`. I have email server with the next settings:

```
# /etc/hostname
mail

# /etc/hosts
127.0.1.1 mail.mydomain.com mail
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

so FQDN is `mail.mydomain.com`.

[Here](https://kb.intermedia.net/article/903) I found examples that I used, but with these examples my server could send emails, but could not receive:

```
Type     Name                Value                                  TTL
A         @                  195.201.40.1                           1 hour  # Web server
A         mail               195.201.40.2                           1 hour  # Mail server
MX        @                  mail.mydomain.com (Priority: 10)       1 hour
TXT       @                  v=spf1 ip4:195.201.40.2 -all           1 hour
TXT       @                  v=DMARC1; p=reject; sp=reject;...      1 hour
TXT       _adsp._domainkey   dkim=all
TXT       dkim._domainkey    v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSq...
```

Then I changed:

```
MX        @   mail.mydomain.com (Priority: 10)  1 hour
```

to

```
MX        mail    mail.mydomain.com (Priority: 10)  1 hour
```

and mail server started to receive emails.

I have two blocks of questions:

1) As I understand, external email services (for example gmail) send mails to `mydomain.com`, not to `mail.mydomain.com`, because my email address looks like `somename@mydomain.com` and not like `somename@mail.mydomain.com`. Why changing `@` to `mail` solved the receiving emails problem?

I understand the record `MX @ mail.mydomain.com` as: "external email service, if you send email to somename@mydomain.com (@ = mydomain.com), then send email to the server with FQDN mail.mydomain.com", but my logic seems does not work. Why?

[Here](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/enom.html#mx) we can see that host name can be `@` with different FQDN. Why in my case it does not work?

2) For TXT records, what Name should I provide? `@` or `mail`, ie domain name or host name? If `mail`, does it mean that if I have 10 mail servers, for all of them I need to make their own TXT records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've translated your DNS records into bind format.  Unless you are changing an entry, you shouldn't need to specify the TTL for an entry.

I've converted the SPF records to the simplest form.  The `A` rule for the `mail` record is for for SPF `-helo` checks.  The rule for `www` indicates that no email should be sent from the `www` sub-domain.

Entries for your domain, sub-domains follow.  (Note the dot at the end of the MX record. If it is missing you should just use `mail`).

```
 @       IN  A    195.201.40.1
         IN  MX   mail.mydomain.com.
         IN  TXT  "v=spf1 mx -all"
```

Standard services mail and www (some browsers will try www even if it isn't supplied in the entry).

```
 mail    IN  A    195.201.40.2 
         IN  TXT  "v=spf1 a -all"
 www     IN  A    195.201.40.1 
         IN  TXT  "v=spf1 -all"
```

Configurration for DMARC with reporting. Until the reports indicate you don't have issues, I would not use a `reject` policy. You may want to start with `none` as your policy.

```
 _dmarc  IN  TXT  "v=DMARC1; p=reject; sp=reject;..."
 *._report.dmarc  IN TXT "v=DMARC1"
```

Configuration for DKIM. `_adsp` doesn't seem to be on the standards track anymore.  Replace `dkim` with the key name you use in when signing.

```
 _adsp._domainkey IN  TXT dkim=all
 dkim._domainkey  IN  TXT  v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSq...
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Mail will be sent to the hostname specified in MX record for the hostname part of email address.
For example, when mail is sent to someone@gmail.com, the following occurs:

One of the configured MX records is taken for gmail.com:

```
# dig mx gmail.com +short | head -n 1
5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

Email is delivered to the IP address of corresponding mail server:

```
# dig gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com +short
173.194.221.27
```

In your case, it is not clear how the issue was resolved since the initial configuration looks good. Try checking which MX server is responsible for your domain name and to which IP address it refers to using public DNS:

```
# dig mx mydomain.com @8.8.8.8 +short
mail.mydomain.com
# dig mail.mydomain.com @8.8.8.8 +short
```

2) Domain name (without `mail.` part) should be provided for SPF record.
As for DKIM and DMARC, prefixes also should be added to the domain name (without `mail.` part), e.g.:

```
TXT       _dmarc             v=DMARC1; p=reject; sp=reject;...
TXT       dkim._domainkey    v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSq...
```